# Send push notification to ios device crash when device token is invalid

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

Im trying to send push notification to multiple ios device, but when one or more tokens are invalids it crash and not send the message to the other devices, here is my code:

```
require_once "libs/ApnsPHP/Autoload.php";
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION,'WenderCastPush.pem');
$pushdevices = array('499D3684-5039-4E56ACB7E285057E8568','21bff83127f8f307b307e828cfe4a65081b7468f980d17f9fbbda05785298c7d');
$push->connect();
foreach ($pushdevices as $device) 
{
    try{
        $message = new ApnsPHP_Message($device);
        $message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-3");
        $message->setBadge(3);
        $message->setText('Message Alert : Testing IOS');
        $message->setSound();
        $message->setExpiry(30);
        $push->add(@$message);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {}    
}
$push->send();
$push->disconnect();
```

Comment: I can't tell by the wording if you are trying to make it crash or make it stop crashing

Comment: Im trying to send to multiple devices but I want to skip all the invalid tokens because when one of the tokens in the array is invalid it crash my push notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How come you are receiving the device token as invalid ones? Its either the developer who's is sending the token to you via web service is messing it up or there is a prob. at you end . Simple solution to this can be , put a check on device token if its above 32 bytes don't save it .

Comment: did the solution helped or you figured it on your own? If Yes please vote for solution

Comment: ok thanks, I have another question how do you access to the data in this array, I tried to create another question but is not posible, this is my code is from firebase: "KOkSVs5vrh1bo_3ua7F":{
"n_user": "Ed",
"pwd": "123456"
"user":"user@firebase.com"}

Comment: I want to access the data inside the element "KOkSVs5vrh1bo_3ua7F" but I can't read the data inside this array